# Can I stop notifications from a Facebook Page I administer going to my personal account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a Facebook Page that I am an administrator of. I have already disabled all email notifications, but here I am referring to notifications that show up within the Facebook interface.

When I am using Facebook under my personal account, I get notifications from the Page, such as who has liked a recent photo or event.

I would like to set it so that I don't see these notifications. I only want notifications relevant to my personal account when I am within my personal account interface, and notifications for my Pages when I am using Facebook within the interface for those Pages.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Admin panel, Beside the "Like" Button, there is a "Follow" option. Click on it to "Unfollow". Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: There was no option to "Unfollow" that I could find, but by not "Liking" the page, notifications have stopped. Interesting that one can be an administrator of a Page that one doesn't "like".

Answer (score 1):

Also in notification section when you click on X button, it will to to unfollow all the feeds from that page.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. This does stop notifications coming in the main feed, but in the right side column, notifications still occur.